# Formatting an input tag to display date

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an input tag which I want to display a date:

```
<input type="text" name="myDate" value="<%: tab.StartDate %>" class="datepicker"/>
```

where 'tab.StartDate' is a field of type DateTime from a linq statement and datepicker is the ajax control.

```
....StartDate = (DateTime)c.StartDate,...
```

The value I saved, for the 2nd March, 2013, is '2013-03-02'.  The value displayed in the above input tag is 32/20/1312.  I see that it is the right date but not formatted properly i.e. the month and first two digits is the year nn/20/13nn

How do I format this to read correctly?

Comment: You can try adding a library to parse dates such as moment.js. You'd manipulate it in the success handler of the ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you simply call the `String.Format` method from the view?

```
<input type="text" name="myDate" value="<%: String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", tab.StartDate) %>" class="datepicker"/>
```